# Financial Force REST API for Journals

Tags: api, financialforce

I'm trying to use the REST API for Journal creation in Financial Force. The path is

```
services/apexrest/c2g/v1.0/journals/*
```

I was able to login, and perform the call but I am receiving an error message

> `<Response [400]>`
>
> [{"message":"Unexpected parameter encountered during deserialization: Company at [line:1, column:17]","errorCode":"JSON_PARSER_ERROR"}]

The JSON I'm passing in the body is

```
{ 
    "Company": "ELIM Company-SEC",
    "Date": "2018-09-01",
    "Currency": "USD",
    "LineItems": [{
            "GeneralLedgerAccount": "181102 - Intermediate Holdings",
            "Value": -11114954.25,
            "LineDescription": "Journal"
        }]
    }
```

Has anyone used this call before? I'm wondering if there's some other key I have to supply in my JSON call prior to the actual journal entry. The documentation on their website doesn't give any indication that is the case though.

http://help.financialforce.com/accounting-api-rest/2018.1/Journals.htm

Update: I did try sending it as a list, wrapped in [ ] but it still errored, with this message

> "Error message": "JSON request body must be an object at [line:1,
> column:2]", "errorCode": "JSON_PARSER_ERROR"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the documentation, it should be an array so your JSON should look like this:

```
[{ 
    "Company": "ELIM Company-SEC",
    "Date": "2018-09-01",
    "Currency": "USD",
    "LineItems": [{
            "GeneralLedgerAccount": "181102 - Intermediate Holdings",
            "Value": -11114954.25,
            "LineDescription": "Journal"
    }]
}]
```

I was able to use your XML to create a Journal in FFA, see screenshot of Workbench below (had to change company and GLA name to match my org):

[image]

You should have enabled the Accounting Journal API in the Feature Console first, can you confirm you have done that? If you are still having problems, it might be an idea to raise a support ticket with FinancialForce.

Comment: I did try the list as well, sorry should have posted that. It still does not work.

Comment: will take a look tomorrow for you

Comment: Edited to show successful response from Workbench.

Comment: Can you advise where I can find the "Feature Console" in FF?

Comment: Hi, its under All Tabs, tab called Feature Console

Comment: I don't have anything called Feature Console. Would it show up in Sandbox or do I have to do it from Production?

Comment: It could be that your user is not setup to have a license for FFA or something and therefore you don't have access to the Tab?

Comment: I reached out to our FF support and was able to get this resolved. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

The documentation shows, albeit not very explicitly, that the JSON structure it's expecting is a *list*, not a map:

```
[{
    "Company": "Merlin Auto AUS",
    <snip>
}]
```

You need to wrap your map up in `[]` so it can be deserialized by the Apex on the receiving side.

Comment: I did try the list as well. Sorry I should have mentioned that. It returns a different error message when you try a list."message": "JSON request body must be an object at [line:1, column:2]",
"errorCode": "JSON_PARSER_ERROR"